# How to access a DOM selector if i don't have access to the html markup in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an application where i use AntDesign. I want to access the next selector:
`span.ant-descriptions-item-content`. The idea is, that i don't have access to html and i don't have the possibility to use `useRef` to access that selector. 
I know that is not ok to use : `document.querySelector('span.ant-descriptions-item-content')` in React, because this is most common for javascript, it si true?
And how to access that selector in case when i don't have access to html?

Comment: why do you want to access it? what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @tudor.gergely, i want to change it depending by some data. I want to use  `if/else`

Comment: On the contrally, you can use the `document` object and it's not necessarily considered a bad practise in `react`.